# chrome developer remote debugging does not screen cast my mobile screen

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-remote-debugging

When I try to debug my cordova applicaton:

```
cordova run android
```

I run it on android USB connected device.

I open the chrome remote desktop: chrome://inspect/#devices

It shows me my connected device. I click on inspect : it opens the remote debuuger (see screenshot)

[image]

**but.. it does not show me my mobile phone screen in chrome. 
and I cannot make any breakpoints neither.**

I remembrer that was working fine on my chrome.

What am I doing wrong ?